# Error response from daemon: Cannot start container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry, dockerhub

```
docker_admin@Ashoka:~$ sudo docker run sqldb
exec format error
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 4e1b251d50ceda05f7b4dd0d3eebd13a731bab0f9a5ed4486f4303d8b5f5b272: [8] System error: exec format error
```

I try to run the image it shows this error, but when I run the same image in interactive mode it runs successful.

Do you know why?

Comment: This is generally due to a mismatch between a 64bit image and a 32bits host architecture... but that would not explain why it works in interactive mode. what is your host, and exact docker version?

Answer (score 1):

This message is produced when the kernel, for whatever reason, doesn't know how to handle the given executable format. It's a problem that's often associated with scripts that don't include a shebang line, or binaries that are incompatible with your system.

Since you're able to run the image interactively, you probably have a badly written script somewhere in your container.

See: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/10668

Answer (score 0):

Try run command using image TAG, execute `docker images` and get your TAG.

```
sudo docker run sqldb:1.0
```

Maybe you need any initial command too

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem just now, in an Alpine 3.5 container running in a Mint 18 host. It's not a very helpful error, and as far as I can tell there is no feature to inspect logs unless the container keeps on running.

The problem was this line in my `Dockerfile`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sleep 500"]
```

I'm using `sleep` at present so I can shell into the container and install a few things experimentally before committing it to the Dockerfile. In fact this would have happened if I had tried to put any command with parameters into a single `ENTRYPOINT` entry. It should have been:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sleep", "500"]
```